# Does Firestore ArrayUnion work with an array of maps?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

EDIT: This question was edited to better highlight the issue. Yes, ArrayUnion does work with an array of maps. But you must be careful to remember that arrayUnion REDUCES duplicate values. For maps, this is not by the objects' references, but by the values in each object. So you must make sure each object is unique (with a unique id, for example) or else merge them by other means (e.g. spread operator).

I have two arrays of maps and need to transfer the values of one onto the other, as shown:

```js
const messages = {
  in: {
    [some_user_id]: [
      {title: 'In message', content: 'In content' },
      {title: 'In message', content: 'In content' }, // EDIT
    ]
  },
  out: {
    [some_user_id]: [{title: 'Out message', content: 'Out content' }]
  },
}
```

When I run:

```js
docRef.update({
  messages: {
    in: { [some_user_id]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.delete(),
    out: { [some_user_id]: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...messages.in[some_user_id])
  }
})
```

there is very unpredictable behavior with multiple messages. Often times, only a single message is transferred. EDIT: The reason being that the two identical objects of messages.in[some_user_id] above are identical.

Is this an issue with arrayUnion and maps, or somehow an issue caused by the delete?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your document? So the fields are clear.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I attempted to recreate the problem in a separate document and was unable to reproduce the error in my local environment. Since I was already reading in the document as part of a transaction, I am just merging the arrays myself and skipping arrayUnion.